# Get the diff between two dates based on 360 days

Tags: php, date, diff

How do I get the difference between two dates based on a 360 days?

360-days: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360-day_calendar

I want to get the difference in days, years and months.

for example:

```
$fechaDT1 = new DateTime($fechauno);
$fechaDT2 = new DateTime($fechados);

//$initialdays = 30 - (float)$fechaDT1->format('d');

$years = $fechaDT1->format('Y') -  $fechaDT2->format('Y');
$months = $fechaDT1->format('m') - $fechaDT2->format('m');
$days = (-$fechaDT1->format('d') + $fechaDT2->format('d'));
$totalDay = $months*30 +$days;
```

solution:

```
    $startDate = new DateTime($startDate);
    $endDate = new DateTime($endDate);
    $initialDays = 30 - $startDate->format('d');

    $year  = ($endDate->format('Y') - $startDate->format('Y')) * 360;
    $meses = ($endDate->format('m') - $startDate->format('m')) * 30;
    $dias  = ($endDate->format('d') - $startDate->format('d'));
    $totalDays = $year+$meses+$dias;

    $years = number_format($totalDias/360);
    $diff = $years - ($endDate->diff($startDate)->y);
    $daysR = $totalDays - (($years-$diff)*360);


    $result = array("days" => $daysR, "years" => ($years-$diff), "initial days" => $initialDays);

    return $result;
```

Comment: you have to explain what you mean by based on 360 days, add some examples or this question will most likely be deleted.

Comment: Anything beyond a number of weeks is problematic because months vary in the number of days and leap years have 366 days. Also, as you may be interested to know, non-leap years have 365 days.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: I edit the post, the problem is solved

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The very best solution:

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-03-24');
$date2 = new DateTime('2014-03-24');
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

// Do whatever you want
echo $diff->days;
var_dump($diff);
```

Reference
[Nettuts article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dates-and-time-the-oop-way--net-35395)

There are many other functional options as well, but today, OOP way is better.

**Update:** 360 days thing

Years:

```
$years = ($diff->days - ($diff->days % 360)) / 360; //+some remaining days if any
```

Month: According to the wiki page and following **The US/NASD Method (30US/360)**:

```
$months = ($diff->days - ($diff->days % 30)) / 30; //+some remaining days if any
```

Comment: is based 360-year not 365 or 366  look this  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360-day_calendar

Comment: Sorry, added related changes to post, but as other commenters said, it is just a workaround, there is no real solution for this. You could probably create your own DateTime classes, but I am not sure that worth the effort.

Comment: I don't really get your example. Why do you make floats? All of those values are integers. But you are right, the days are calculated based on 365-day/year standard, so that is not working this way. But your example could be the way. Just don't get why you cast integer values to float.

Comment: ok no problem i  remove values float, was to fix something that happened, but they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Python also but I think this will work:

```
import datetime as dt
import calendar
```

Calculate days difference based on 30/360 calendar
*formats* 
date1   :   date format (2020-01-01)
date2   :   date format (2020-01-01)

```
def days_360 (date1, date2):
    days_diff = (date2.year - date1.year) * 360;
    days_diff += (date2.month - date1.month) * 30;
    days_diff += (date2.day - date1.day);
    return days_diff;
```